# How to filter related CorelationIDs by OperationName

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, azure-monitoring

I'd like to create a query where I can filter out all OperationName instances of start, stop, and restart events along with their CorrelationID. For example, if a start event ("Microsoft.Web/sites/start/action") occurs, can I get the CorrelationID of that event and all instances of that CorrelationID, then remove those as well?

[image]

I've been able to successfully filter out the OperationName events, but I'm not sure how to go about getting the CorrelationID that are attached to them, and then how to remove the extra lines left behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used sample data and first took `distinct` *CorrelationIds* for *OperationName* which `contains` *start/stop/restart*.  Now used `rightanti` join on *CorrelationId* column and got the result.
`rightanti` join will return rows from right table which has no matching records in left table.

Below is **sample code** used.

```
let  tbl = datatable(TimeGenerated :datetime ,OperationName : string, Level : string, ActivityStatus : string, ActivitySubStatus : string, CorrelationId : string )
[
datetime(2023-03-16 07:43:44.757),"Microsoft.Web/sites/stop/action", "Informational", "Started","","f5c60ac6-d246-4ddf-abb3-4fdcb8b7b50b",
datetime(2023-03-16 07:43:44.757),"", "Information", "","","f5c60ac6-d246-4ddf-abb3-4fdcb8b7b50b",
datetime(2023-03-16 07:43:44.913),"", "Information", "","","f5c60ac6-d246-4ddf-abb3-4fdcb8b7b50b",
datetime(2023-03-16 07:43:44.913),"Microsoft.Web/sites/stop/action", "Informational", "Succeeded","OK (HTTP Status Code: 200)","f5c60ac6-d246-4ddf-abb3-4fdcb8b7b50b",
datetime(2023-03-16 07:43:46.636),"Microsoft.Web/sites/start/action", "Informational", "Started","","3a4494be-6d35-4eee-b844-5bc17a500a05",
datetime(2023-03-16 07:43:46.636),"", "Information", "","","3a4494be-6d35-4eee-b844-5bc17a500a05",
datetime(2023-03-16 07:43:46.058),"Microsoft.Web/sites/start/action", "Informational", "Succeeded","OK (HTTP Status Code: 200)","3a4494be-6d35-4eee-b844-5bc17a500a05",
datetime(2023-03-16 07:43:46.058),"", "Information", "","","3a4494be-6d35-4eee-b844-5bc17a500a05",
datetime(2023-03-16 07:44:40.007),"microsoft.insights/diagnosticSetting", "Informational", "Started","","436b3140-d42d-477e-978b-de9eb63221d4",
datetime(2023-03-16 07:44:40.678),"microsoft.insights/diagnosticSetting", "Informational", "Succeeded","OK (HTTP Status Code: 200)","436b3140-d42d-477e-978b-de9eb63221d4",
datetime(2023-03-16 08:42:06.822),"", "Information", "","","8793b951-4e49-4bbc-b47e-de8513a01108",
datetime(2023-03-16 08:42:06.822),"microsoft.insights/diagnosticSetting", "Informational", "Started","","8793b951-4e49-4bbc-b47e-de8513a01108",
datetime(2023-03-16 08:42:07.478),"", "Information", "","","8793b951-4e49-4bbc-b47e-de8513a01108"
];
tbl
| where  OperationName  contains  "start"  or  OperationName  contains  "stop"  or  OperationName  contains  "restart"
| distinct  CorrelationId
| join  kind = rightanti  tbl  on  CorrelationId
```

**Source Table**
[image]

**Result**
[image]